# Sum rows in 2d numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Assume the following 2d numpy is given:

```
myNP = np.array([[5., 2., 1.],
                [3., 3., 3.],
                [3., 3., 3.]])
```

One has to find the weight of each point in each row in relation to the sum of the row.

in reference to the example above the expected result need to be:

```
([[0.625, 0.25 , 0.125],
  [0.333, 0.333, 0.333],
  [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]])
```

Comment: Indeed it gives a solution

Comment: `myNP/myNP.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myNP_weight = (myNP/myNP.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)).round(3)
```

Or

```
myNP_weight = (myNP/myNP.sum(axis=1)[:, None]).round(3)
```

**Output**:

```
>>> print(myNP_weight)
array([[0.625, 0.25 , 0.125],
       [0.333, 0.333, 0.333],
       [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]])
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

the sum function does exactly what you need. You just need to specify the axis. In your case `myNP.sum(axis=1)` should do the trick